# Sanitizing JSON Strings without \

Tags: python, json, serialization

Given successful query from SQL SELECT result, there are json output with \n and \ . That makes me confusions and obstacles to deserialise the json string into array of objects. Would you please tell me the way to replace all those json strings without newlines , spaces, and also blackslashes `\` ?

```
  dicts = [dict(row) for row in result]
  j = json.dumps(dicts ,  sort_keys=True,
  indent=None,
  default=default , separators=(',', ':'))

  return {
    'result':  j
  }
```

Here is my output json with many back slashes `\`

```
{"result": "[{\"_access\":[{\"level\":\"read\",\"public\":true}],\"_created_at\":\"2019-05-26T09:57:10.494525\",\"_created_by\":\"473ee711-19a0-4309-8cb2-7f672fd93224\",\"_database_id\":\"\",\"_id\":\"3f674e29-29ba-4dcf-b9d9-f99a3c35866e\",\"_owner_id\":\"473ee711-19a0-4309-8cb2-7f672fd93224\",\"_updated_at\":\"2019-05-26T10:01:14.691527\",\"_updated_by\":\"473ee711-19a0-4309-8cb2-7f672fd93224\",\"book_label\":\"B198\",\"deleted_at\":null,\"deleted_by\":null,\"free_assign_date\":null,\"free_assign_end_date\":null,\"is_completed\":false,\"is_free_assigned\":true,\"progress_chapter\":1,\"total_chapters\":2,\"user_label\":\"user10\"}]"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `["result"]` entry in the dict is a string. You just simply need to parse it. `json.dumps` does the opposite of what you are looking for - converts JSON to a string. You want `json.loads`, which converts a string to JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
result_str = "[{\"_access\":[{\"level\":\"read\",\"public\":true}],\"_created_at\":\"2019-05-26T09:57:10.494525\",\"_created_by\":\"473ee711-19a0-4309-8cb2-7f672fd93224\",\"_database_id\":\"\",\"_id\":\"3f674e29-29ba-4dcf-b9d9-f99a3c35866e\",\"_owner_id\":\"473ee711-19a0-4309-8cb2-7f672fd93224\",\"_updated_at\":\"2019-05-26T10:01:14.691527\",\"_updated_by\":\"473ee711-19a0-4309-8cb2-7f672fd93224\",\"book_label\":\"B198\",\"deleted_at\":null,\"deleted_by\":null,\"free_assign_date\":null,\"free_assign_end_date\":null,\"is_completed\":false,\"is_free_assigned\":true,\"progress_chapter\":1,\"total_chapters\":2,\"user_label\":\"user10\"}]"

js_obj = json.loads(result_str)

print json.dumps(js_obj)
```

have a try